# dropdown menu not responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make my navigation bar responsive depending on the screen size. At the moment all is working except when the screen gets too small that it shows the 'hamburger' bars, all links under the button are not displayed. Also when clicking on the hamburger bars not all links are displayed vertical and again not all links under services are shown.

Ive tried changing the css for the dropdown.content but so far nothing is working.

```css
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="myNavBar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Services 
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
       </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Red or Black Tarmac Drives and Paths</a>
      <a href="#">Fencing and Gates</a>
      <a href="#">Shingle and Coloured Gravels</a>
      <a href="#">Drainage Work</a>
      <a href="#">Patios and Crazy Paving</a>
      <a href="#">Block Paved Driveways and Paths</a>
      <a href="#">Turfing and Artificial Grass</a>
      <a href="#">Brick and Purbeck Stone Walls</a>
      <a href="#">Decking and Rockeries</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /dropdown-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /dropdown -->
  <a href="#home">Gallary</a>
  <a href="#home">Before and After</a>
  <a href="#home">Testimonials</a>
  <a href="#home">Contact Us</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- /navbar -->

<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
```

I have put this in a jsfiddle and below is the link

https://jsfiddle.net/knrvmdu5/

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This rule `.navbar a:not(:first-child) {display:none;}` is hiding links under Services button. Easiest solution is to either completely change your hiding rules or add a rule to override this hiding effect, e.g. `.navbar .dropdown-content a {display:block;} `

Comment: @sztrzask that great thank you for looking at my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed all of your `float` rules and replaced them with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Floats are hard to manage, and I can tell you had to add `overflow: hidden` to your `.navbar` to make sure it would show the floated elements and that's one of the reasons your services menu was cut-off. I also added unique classes to the links so you can target them easier. Your rule for `.navbar a:not(first-child)` was causing your nested services menu links to not appear:

```css
/* ========== NAVIGATION BAR ========== */

.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar a {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {
  .nav-link:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.icon {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {
  .navbar.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .navbar.responsive a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="navbar" id="myNavBar">
      <div class="links">
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Services 
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Red or Black Tarmac Drives and Paths</a>
            <a href="#">Fencing and Gates</a>
            <a href="#">Shingle and Coloured Gravels</a>
            <a href="#">Drainage Work</a>
            <a href="#">Patios and Crazy Paving</a>
            <a href="#">Block Paved Driveways and Paths</a>
            <a href="#">Turfing and Artificial Grass</a>
            <a href="#">Brick and Purbeck Stone Walls</a>
            <a href="#">Decking and Rockeries</a>
          </div>
          <!-- /dropdown-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /dropdown -->
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Gallery</a>
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Before and After</a>
        <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Testimonials</a>
      <a href="#home" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar -->

    <div style="padding-left:16px">
      <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
      <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myNavBar");
        if (x.className === "navbar") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "navbar";
        }
      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```